# How to mock/patch whole class?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I have following code:

```
pkg1/mock_class.py:

class A:
    def ma(self):
        print(' class_A')


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 'vvv'

    def mb(self):
        a = A()
        print('class_B')
        a.ma()
```

and test code:

```
from unittest import mock
import pytest
from pkg1.mock_class import B


@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def mockA():
    with mock.patch('pkg1.mock_class.A'):
        yield

class TestB:
    def test_b(self, mockA):
        b = B()
        b.mb()
```

I want to mock whole class A () using fixture and i would like to be able to configure some return values probably using parametrization in future.

Basic - just mocking/patching as implemented above is not working class B is mocked and i don't understand why.

Thanks for advice.

Jano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code above is working correctly, i thought it is not working because in real scenario it wasnt - i was patching incorrect place.

from official documentation ([link](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch)):

> patch() works by (temporarily) changing the object that a name points
>   to with another one. There can be many names pointing to any
>   individual object, so for patching to work you must ensure that you
>   patch the name used by the system under test.
>
> The basic principle is that you patch where an object is looked up,
>   which is not necessarily the same place as where it is defined. A
>   couple of examples will help to clarify this.